Can I retrieve properties from a SharePoint document library with GraphAPI SDK using only a single GetAsync call?
I currently have the following code:
var site = await ctx
    .Sites["mytenancy.sharepoint.com:/sites/TestSite"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

var docLib = await ctx
    .Sites[site.Id]
    .Drives
    .Request()
    .Filter($"name eq 'TestLibrary'")
    .GetAsync();

This code works (sort of) but there are two network roundtrips involved here, and I want to consolidate the two calls for performance reasons. However, when I do that:
var docLib = await ctx
    .Sites["mytenancy.sharepoint.com:/sites/TestSite"]
    .Drives
    .Request()
    .Filter($"name eq 'TestLibrary'")
    .GetAsync();

I get the following exception:
Status Code: NotFound
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: itemNotFound
Message: The provided path does not exist, or does not represent a site

What am I doing wrong? Also, the first code fragment, which I expect to return a single document library, instead returns all the document libraries of the site. Clearly I'm doing something wrong there too.
